# Elements of first list in Kendall must be ordered?

Tags: r, pearson-r, kendall-tau

Two ways to execute a Kendall tau test (in R):

```
# Order of first list as advertised in Kendall test.
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y1 <- c(2,1,4,3,6,5)

# Should give the same Kendall score,
# because ID's of elements are only permuted.
x2 <- c(6,4,3,5,2,1)
y2 <- c(4,6,5,3,1,2)

library("Kendall")
summary( Kendall(x1, y1) )
cat("------------------------------\n")
summary( Kendall(x2, y2) )
```

Gives different correlation indexes:

```
Score =  9 , Var(Score) = 28.33333
denominator =  15
tau = 0.6, 2-sided pvalue = 0.13285
------------------------------
Score =  5 , Var(Score) = 28.33333
denominator =  15
tau = 0.333, 2-sided pvalue = 0.45237
```

In my view the counting of concordant and dis-concordant pairs should be invariant under permutation.   Or at least invariant under element-naming.  Apparently, I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

You permuted your variables *independently of each other*.  Observe:

[image]

I don't see why that should yield the same output.  On the other hand, if you shuffle them identically, you get the same results (as you should).  Consider:

```
x3 = x1[c(4,2,5,1,6,3)]
y3 = y1[c(4,2,5,1,6,3)]

summary( Kendall(x1, y1) )
# Score =  9 , Var(Score) = 28.33333
# denominator =  15
# tau = 0.6, 2-sided pvalue =0.13285
summary( Kendall(x3, y3) )
# Score =  9 , Var(Score) = 28.33333
# denominator =  15
# tau = 0.6, 2-sided pvalue =0.13285
```

Comment: it's not important on its own, but if you edit your answer at some point you might want fix the typo when you're doing that (*permutted* has more '*t*'s than the usual convention)